# Fileuploader not triggering the actionListener

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am trying to upload a file using rich:fileUploader and its not triggering the uploadListener be it whatever.

Here is the code, let me know if something is missing :)

```
    <f:view>
    <a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js" />
    <h:form id="uploadFileForm" prependId="false">
        <rich:fileUpload immediateUpload="true"
            listHeight="150px;" noDuplicate="true" listWidth="350px;" 
            maxFilesQuantity="1" locale="de" 
            fileUploadListener="#{paramFileUpload.fileUploadsListener}">
        </rich:fileUpload>          
    </h:form>
    </f:view>

public void fileUploadsListener(UploadEvent event) {
    LOGGER.info("In ActionListener of file upload");
    UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
    LOGGER.info("item : " + item.getFileSize() + ", " + item.getContentType() + ", " + item.getData());
    if(item.getFile() != null) {
        LOGGER.info("File name and size : " + item.getFile().getPath() + ", " + item.getFile().getTotalSpace());
    }
}
```

This is in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When page is loaded , the firebug console shows errro as below :

```
parentForm is null
ProgressBar={};ProgressBar=Class.creat...' {parentForm=parentForm.parentNode;}
```

And when file is chosen from file browser,

```
this.progressBar is undefined
if(this.labelMarkup){var progressData=...._fileSizeScriptTimeoutId=undefined;}
```

Comment: My code to file upload is pretty much like yours, and I have the same configurations in web.xml. Verify that there are no nested forms in your page.

Comment: No, there are no nested forms in the page. I still dont figure out what could be wrong in here :(

Comment: Very odd. By the way, have you tested a page where's only the `fileUpload` component? Maybe its just a configuration for scripts, check your web.xml the context param `org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy` I have setted with value `ALL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to do it the `tomahawk` way by defining a servlet in `web.xml` and using `t:inputFileUpload` to upload the file. This will inturn trigger my backing bean to yield a UploadedFile :)